# Loop is not ending in perl

Tags: perl

I want this kind of output:

```
job cpu-param-14.25.sh 
job gpu-param-14.25.sh
..
..
job cpu-param-15.75.sh 
job gpu-param-15.75.sh

job cpu-param-16.25.sh 
job gpu-param-16.25.sh
..
job cpu-param-18.sh 
job gpu-param-18.sh
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$incr=0.25;

my $filename = 'job-submit-14.25-18.sh';

open (my $BATCHFILE, '>', "$filename");

$dihed=14.25;
while ($dihed <= 18.0) {
    if ($dihed != 16.0) {
        $dihed += $incr;
    }

    print $BATCHFILE
    "
    job cpu-param-$dihed.sh 
    job gpu-param-$dihed.sh
    "
}

close ($BATCHFILE);
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$incr=0.25;
...
$dihed=14.25;
while ($dihed <= 18.0) {
    if ($dihed != 16.0) {
        $dihed += $incr;
    }
    ...
}
```

This loop starts with `$dihed` being `14.25` and you increment it in each step by `$incr` being 0.25. This way `$dihed` will eventually reach `16.0`.  This case is explicitly handled in your code so that it does not increase `$dihed`, which means `$dihed` will always stay `16.0` from then on and your code will loop forever.

Given the description of what your output should be (i.e. that it should ignore the `16.0`) it is more likely that your code should instead always increment but skip the output for `16.0`:

```
$incr=0.25;
...
$dihed=14.25;
while ($dihed <= 18.0) {
    $dihed += $incr;
    if ($dihed == 16.0) {
        next; # skip output for 16.0
    }
    ...
}
```